# what to do with this error?

Tags: php, user-registration

I have had my script running on a localhost WampServer 1st which where it worked and then exported it to my online live domain.
After some adjustments i got the script partically working again but i am still getting below error

```
Call to undefined function filter_var()
```

The purpose of this script is when an user wants to registrate it will validate the email address and add the user to the database and send an validation link to the users emailaddress.

Here is the script:

```
<?PHP
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
// connection towards database with a include function
include ('connection.php');

if (isset($_REQUEST['send']))
{
    if(isset($_REQUEST['NAAM']))
    {
        $naam = $_REQUEST['NAAM'];
    }

    function spamcheck($field)
    {
        //filter_var() sanitizes the e-mail
        //address using FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL
        $field = filter_var($field, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

        //filter_var() validates the e-mail
        //address using FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL
        if(filter_var($field, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
        {
            return TRUE;
        }else
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    //if "email" is filled out, proceed
    if (isset($_REQUEST['mail']))
    {

        //check if the email address is invalid
        $mailCheck = spamcheck($_REQUEST['mail']);
        if ($mailCheck == TRUE)
        {
            $email = $_REQUEST['mail'];
        }else
        {
            $mailCheck = FALSE;
            echo "Invalid input email";
        }
    }

    if(isset($_REQUEST['question']))
    {
        $quest = $_REQUEST['question'];
        // checks if the filled in Question is de same as the answer novice or Novice
        if ($quest =="novice" or $quest =="Novice")
        {
            $questCheck = TRUE;
        }else
        {
            $questCheck = FALSE;
            echo "Your answer to the question was incorrect!<br>";
        }
    }

    if(isset($_REQUEST['wachtwoord'] , $_REQUEST['c_wachtwoord']))
    {

        $WW = $_REQUEST['wachtwoord'];
        $c_WW = $_REQUEST['c_wachtwoord'];

        // checks if the filled in password is de same as the confirmation password
        if ($WW == $c_WW)
        {
            $pwCheck = TRUE;
        }else
        {
            $pwCheck = FALSE;
            echo "Your filled in passwords are not the same try again!<BR>";
        }
    }       



    // checks if both password confirmation and question are TRUE continue else retrieve fault
    if ($pwCheck && $questCheck && $mailCheck == TRUE)
    {
        $hash = md5( rand(0,1000) );
        // insert all filled in values into the database
        $opdracht1 = "INSERT INTO users (ID , name , password , mail , staffLevel , hash , active) VALUES ('','$naam','$WW','$email','0','$hash','0')";

        // run query 
        if (mysql_query ($opdracht1))
        {
            header( "refresh:5;url=http://www.debeerislos.nl/inlog_user.php" );
            echo "Your account has succesfully been created! Please check your email to validate your account!<BR>";

                    $to      = $email; //Send email to our user
                    $subject = 'Signup | Verification'; //// Give the email a subject 
                    $message = '

                    Thanks for signing up!
                    Your account has been created!
                    You can login with the following credentials:

                    ------------------------
                    Username: '.$naam.'
                    Password: '.$WW.'
                    ------------------------

                    After you have activated your account you will have the rights so you can fully use it.

                    Please click this link to activate your account:
                    http://www.debeerislos.nl/verify_user.php?email='.$email.'&hash='.$hash.'&name='.$naam.'

                    '; // Our message above including the link

                    $headers = 'From:info@debeerislos.nl' . "\r\n"; // Set from headers
                    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); // Send the email

        }else
        {
            echo "Woops something went wrong please contact the Administrator of the website or fill in the form again!<br> <A href='http://www.debeerislos.nl/form_register_user.html'>CLICK HERE!</A> to fill in the forum again";
        }
    }elseif ($pwCheck && $questCheck == FALSE)
    {
        echo "you filled both the password confirmation and the answer to the question incorrect!<br>";
    }       
}else
{
    echo "Either you haven't send anything! or you haven't filled in the form<br>";
}
?>
```

In advance thank you.

Kind Regards,
StaleDevil

Comment: What php version do you have?

Comment: Check your PHP version is >= 5.2

Answer (score 0):

where have you defined `filter_var()` function? It is not defined in your given code. If you are defining it in the same page then how are you defining? provide example. otherwise if you are definfing it in another page then include the page.

Comment: It's a PHP 5.2+ native function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

Comment: please read the script more carefully it's right here

 function spamcheck($field)
    {
        //filter_var() sanitizes the e-mail
        //address using FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL
        $field = filter_var($field, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

        //filter_var() validates the e-mail
        //address using FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL
        if(filter_var($field, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
        {